# Icmp ping and dns ports for pihole on google cloud doesnt work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, icmp

I opened all ports on Google cloud firewall but i still cant ping my server nor dns ports.
Any advice. I have used digital ocean in past but it was easy .Never managed to make it work in google cloud. They dont have even a free trial support..

Comment: I've added more information to my answer, please let me know if some of the options worked for you, and if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default there are some Firewall rules created for your project in the `default` VPC  network, and one of these rules allows the ping from internal and external IPs.

But if you already delete them You can re-create the rule with the following command:

```
gcloud compute --project=<<PROJECT-ID>> firewall-rules create icmpnew --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=icmp --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

To discard problems that could be in your premise network you can ping your instance from [this site](https://www.subnetonline.com/pages/network-tools/online-ping-ipv4.php).

Additionally, If you have a Free trial account you can have chat support through  [Console Support Center](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.201203500.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739), also, you can visit the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/support) for more information.

#### Edit1

You also can check the configuration from your OS, if you are using a Linux,If you want to allow it for everyone,  try to specify the mask after the IP address.

from:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0 -d 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

to:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

Also you are using Windows, you can open the port or allow a protocol in a firewall with the following steps:

1. From the **Start** menu, click **Control Panel**, click **System and Security**, and then click **Windows Firewall**. Control Panel is not configured for 'Category' view, you only need to select **Windows Firewall**.
2. Click **Advanced Settings**.
3. Click **Inbound Rules**.
4. From the rules listed under Inbound Rules, select “File and printer Sharing (Echo Request – ICMPv4-In)” and enable the rule.
   [image]
5. Click Finish.
6. **Restart** the Instance.

I hope this information would be useful to you